`pip install .` successfully installs - but calling raises: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named - importing it works fine
Quick description: CLI made with click that interacts with spotify using dbus-python. Go to the github page if you need more info I suppose - or try it yourself if you are so inclined. I'm running on an ubuntu-vm ATM.
To reproduce:

I have my own package, when I pip install -e . the package install fine and it can be called in the terminal.

$ spotzero works

clone the repo again just in case

I pip install . without the --editable flat, the package also install without any errors. But calling it on the terminal returns an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotzero'


ubuntu2204@ubuntu2204-vm:~/Downloads/spotzero$ spotzero
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu2204/.local/bin/spotzero", line 5, in <module>
    from spotzero.cli import cli
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotzero'

So far I have tried:

Wiping the spotzero folder and cloning it again and doing pip install .  again. This changed the output a little, but the issue still stands:

Running with the --editable flag works.

The weirdest part is that importing the package is fine..?


(spotzero) ubuntu2204@ubuntu2204-vm:~/Downloads/spotzero$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spotzero
>>> import spotzero.cli as spotzero
>>> spotzero
<module 'spotzero.cli' from '/home/ubuntu2204/Documents/spotzero/spotzero/cli.py'>
>>> spotzero.resume() # this works


Ran on Fedora 39 and a freshly installed ubuntu 22.04 machine

I have tried so far:

after pip successful installed: ModuleNotFoundError
I fixed this but it isn't why I made the post: pip installs packages successfully, but executables not found from command line
This is someone running into the same issue, solves it by adding the -e flag: ModuleNotFoundError after pip install . (custom module)
Many many more stackoverflow questions that I don't remember
Tied running from the folder above and doing pip install spotzero (the folder)


The setup.py seems incorrect to me. spotzero is clearly a import package (i.e. there is a spotzero/__init__.py file), but it is listed in py_modules in setup.py. It should be listed in packages instead. -- You can probably debug this by creating a wheel, and inspecting its content.

On setup.py I changed
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="spotzero",
    version="0.1.0",
    # py_modules=["spotzero"], -> This makes it no worky
    install_requires=["dbus-python==1.3.2", "click>=8.1"],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "spotzero = spotzero.cli:cli",
        ],
    },
)

And this makes python -m build work. If I then pip install dist/...whl then this works. I still don't understand why the --editable tag is required but oh well.
However, when uploading to PyPI, it works just fine. Because building works.
